# Network load balancing: LACP between Debian & FreeNAS over Cisco Switch doesn't work

Tags: networking, cisco, load-balancing, lacp

My setup:
2 Debian Server, with Bonding
2 Storage Server FreeNAS with Link Aggregation
1 Cisco Switch SG-200 with LAG enabled
MTU 9000 enabled everywhere

Result: Network performance is still single lane...

Here a picture of my config:
[Config](http://files.fuerst.it/lag.png)
I guess there is a mistake in the switch config. but there is nothing else to configure.
Just to define ports for each LAG, which i made. All LAG are "Link up".

Maybe i can provide you with more information to make it more clear.
Just tell me what you need.

THANKS 
Steve

Answer (score 2):

I'll be honest I'm much more experienced with Cisco's proprietry 'Etherchannel' mechanism but as far as I know LACP works the same way in that channel transmission selection is based on the least significant 1, 2 or 3 bits of the destination MAC address. This works fine if you have lots of different destinations, it really does smooth out the traffic across the various channels but in a situation where you only have a single destination all traffic will go down the same channel and will never make use of any other link.

I think this is your problem, forgive me if my 'Cisco blindness' means this is wrong.

Comment: Ahh i guess i know it, but first thanks for your reply. Now i checked once again config of servers and i found out that all 3 NIC's have the same MAC address... i will change it to different, in hope that i finally have more performance.

Comment: Chopper3 is right. Link aggregation allows the *total* speed of the bond to be the total of the slaves. The *maximum* speed is the speed of a single slave. I assume you are using NFS or ISCSI or something else which is one TCP connection? You cannot load balance that. If you need faster than one slave, get faster NICs.

Comment: But if i just check the connection with iperf (with several connections) i should be able to get maximum performance on each lane and also in total.

Comment: This is true, *ONLY IF* each iperf connection is load balanced out a different slave.